# Stateless NHibernate for querying

Tags: nhibernate

We have a database that is updated via a background process. We are using NHibernate to query the data for display on the web UI, so we don't need change tracking or lazy-loading.

If we mark all the mappings as mutable="false", is this the same as using a stateless session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not the same. In fact, it has absolutely nothing to do with it (i.e. you can modify entities in stateless sessions).

A StatelessSession does not keep track of entities, which results in big performance improvements (both in memory usage and execution times) when you don't need the features that a stateful session provides.

In particular:

- There is no lazy loading
- There is no caching
- There is no cascading
- All updates must be explicit (insert/update/delete)

Comment: But does marking mutable="false" mean the entity will not be tracked?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only means it will not be *updated* once it's persistant, but that's just a flag; all the plumbing is still there.